# Remove duplicates based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a multiple fields Primary Key that consists of (col1,col2,col3). 
However, before the PK was added, there have been a lot of duplicates added which need to be removed.

So for my table if I have:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
---- ---- ----
  2    3   3
  2    3   3
  2    3   4
  2    4  null
  2    4  null
```

the query should result in

```
 Col1 Col2 Col3
 ---- ---- ----
  2    3   3
  2    3   4
  2    4  null
```

Only 3rd column is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

use `distinct`

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3
from tablename
```

Comment: This doesn't actually _remove_ any records, it only presents the view the OP wants.